# Jquery Filter through multiple xml nodes with same name

Tags: jquery, xml, filter

I'm attempting to pull information from an XML file from different nodes with the same name. The way the programmers typed it out originally, it pulls from a single node that's easily extrapolated. I've previously modified the code to segregate out a single aspect into a cookie but now i need to take it further. I need to use a complex filter to identify values from up to 5 different nodes and push them to different variables. Essentially, i need it to be select value from node named daypart where daypart name = something (i'm an SQL guy, not a web admin).

I do not know very much about jquery but i know there's a way to do this with filters. I've included a snippet of the xml file so you can see. i need to pull carsserved and nummetgoal out where the currentdaypartname = (in this case) breakfast. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <LaneMetrics>
<DriveThruLane1ServiceGoal>
  <AllDayParts>
    <DayPart>
      <AverageServiceTime>03:41</AverageServiceTime>
      <RecentAverageServiceTime>03:15</RecentAverageServiceTime>
      <TargetServiceTime>03:00</TargetServiceTime>
      <AverageServiceTimeSeconds>222</AverageServiceTimeSeconds>
      <RecentAverageServiceTimeSeconds>195</RecentAverageServiceTimeSeconds>
      <TargetServiceTimeSeconds>180</TargetServiceTimeSeconds>
      <PercentOnTarget>44%</PercentOnTarget>
      <CarsServed>81</CarsServed>
      <NumMetGoal>36</NumMetGoal>
      <ReportingName>DriveThruLane 1</ReportingName>
      <CurrentDaypartName>Breakfast</CurrentDaypartName>
      <CurrentDaypartCategory>ServicePeriod</CurrentDaypartCategory>
    </DayPart>
    <DayPart>
      <AverageServiceTime>03:58</AverageServiceTime>
      <RecentAverageServiceTime>02:43</RecentAverageServiceTime>
      <TargetServiceTime>04:00</TargetServiceTime>
      <AverageServiceTimeSeconds>238</AverageServiceTimeSeconds>
      <RecentAverageServiceTimeSeconds>163</RecentAverageServiceTimeSeconds>
      <TargetServiceTimeSeconds>240</TargetServiceTimeSeconds>
      <PercentOnTarget>57%</PercentOnTarget>
      <CarsServed>14</CarsServed>
      <NumMetGoal>8</NumMetGoal>
      <ReportingName>DriveThruLane 1</ReportingName>
      <CurrentDaypartName>Lunch</CurrentDaypartName>
      <CurrentDaypartCategory>ServicePeriod</CurrentDaypartCategory>
    </DayPart>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JQuery:** 
Try **.each** to loop through the XML and find the matched values.

You can use the below loop:

```
$(xml).find('DayPart').each(function(index){
    if($(this).find('CurrentDaypartName').text() == "Breakfast"){
        alert("carsserved :" + $(this).find('CarsServed').text() + " and NumMetGoal : " + $(this).find('NumMetGoal').text())
    }  
 });
```

**JavaScript:**

```
xml = xml.getElementsByTagName('DayPart');

for(var i=0; i < xml.length;i++){    
    if(xml[i].getElementsByTagName('CurrentDaypartName')[0].innerHTML == "Breakfast"){
        alert("carsserved :" + xml[i].getElementsByTagName('CarsServed')[0].innerHTML + " and NumMetGoal : " + xml[i].getElementsByTagName('NumMetGoal')[0].innerHTML)
    }   
}
```

Comment: that looks like it would work but i tore into the code a little more and now feel sheepish. It's javascript, not jquery. i got focused on jquery because of a post i saw. My apologies.                     Can that be modified for javascript?

Comment: You can find the Javascript equivalent snippet above.

Comment: yeah. not working.    I've tweakedi ta  bit to give me an alert that shows the value so that i will know if it's pulling from the right place and it's coming up undefined.             
Temp_XML = g_XmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('DayPart');

for(var i=0; i < Temp_XML.length;i++){    
alert(Temp_XML[i].getElementsByTagName('AverageServiceTime')[0].Text)

Comment: The sub portion that says 'getElementsByTagName('AverageServiceTime')[0].innerHTML) is returning "undefined" which means it's not triggering the if / then statement. I've tried selectSingleNode and it just errors out.

Comment: Could you please put your code in codepen or jsfiddle and give me the link, So that I can debug and fix the issue.

Comment: Never Mind. I got it to work. I converted the text value of the node to a string which contained all the values of the child nodes. i then extracted the needed numbers.

Comment: Great. Happy coding !!